# Is it possible to share an image on Android via a data URL?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, graphics

Is it possible to share an image with code something like this?

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setData(Uri.parse("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACx"
    + "jwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAGoSURBVDhPlVM9SEJRGD2DkL+QmoiKYNggToJL"
    + "4KKLNDiKW4NCoENQkzS1uboILoKjW61NSZOjo1uOBlHPgjJsuN3jvc+naVQHPt79vu+cc9/37n34"
    + "BQkd/0Jibw+3Ozt4j0TwwuCaNfYU5Qe43Tg5OMDD9TWEYUAIoYJr1mIxPEmjc01fh8uF03wer6vC"
    + "7zGbQZRKmPp8uNCyJWKhEAwSTDJ3NNc07fUsE76J1FjjcL5VQb0O4XBAVCoqj0ZV3u2qvN+H8Psx"
    + "1HLAZsPn6u6pFIQsi3AYYjKBcDpVXiyqPrl2O2ayZqc+FY9jaooZuZwSJBJL8iKv1SwONdTSIJtO"
    + "w1g1GA4h9vfVk3mjod5mPLY4ySQMqT2kgZ0jsMjZBgOL9D1omM2qtfwmH1K7SwN4vbhnkzuQ0G5v"
    + "imnOHjkMjwePC7HGUSajxuDM1aqa/+wM4vJSCRnmHSkU8CwNjrVWIRDAVauFubnjaATRbCoD7m7W"
    + "Ox3Mg0HcaNkaduV9GPCmbbuNrLEnxXeSuzi+reD/wJ+Hx1Qu443BNWvsadqfwDOu6lic9yaAL2uK"
    + "Y4RMd4E2AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, getString(R.id.menu_share)));
```

My goal is to make my app not require permissions to write to storage, but to be able to share images that it dynamically creates. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Comment: @WilliamKinaan I don't see anything about embedding images into intents in the article you linked.

Comment: this is the section http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#intent_pickimage

Comment: @WilliamKinaan That appears to be demonstrating how to pick a photo from the device. The picture I am trying to send is not saved on the device. It is dynamically drawn/generated on the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to share an image with code something like this?

No, because `ACTION_SEND` does not use the `Uri`. It uses `EXTRA_TEXT` or `EXTRA_STREAM`.

> My goal is to make my app not require permissions to write to storage, but to be able to share images that it dynamically creates. Is there any way to do this?

Create a `ContentProvider` to serve the file, then put the `Uri` pointing to your file within your provider in `EXTRA_STREAM`. You *may* be able to protect the provider with a custom permission and allow the sending activity temporary access to it via `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`, though I have only tried that with `Intent` structures that use the actual `Uri` (e.g., `setData()`) instead of via an extra like `EXTRA_STREAM`.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/GrantUriPermissions) demonstrates this technique using `ACTION_VIEW` (note: requires a device with a PDF viewer installed to truly work).

Comment: This works great! I simply put the Uri in the second parameter of putExtra, and it figured out how to get the image via the ContentProvider-linked Uri! It must have used the overload that accepts a string as a second parameter. Do you recommend I post any further details about my specific solution and how it worked in this topic anywhere? I think this is a pretty cool solution, but I'm not sure what details others might want to see here. Certainly the code you linked to answered a lot of my questions, but I did have to be smart enough to go looking at the manifest file too.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: Please, share some info on how you did it. I am trying to do the exact same thing.