# How do I provide an image to Facebook via ContentProvider?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I am implementing a `ContentProvider` in order to send data to other apps without writing them to external storage. (See [How to implement a ContentProvider for providing image to Gmail, Facebook, Evernote, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865979/how-to-implement-a-contentprovider-for-providing-image-to-gmail-facebook-evern)). Nowever, it appears Facebook is not playing nice (or I don't know how to answer nice). It executes query on my `ContentProvider`, and includes "_data" (`MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA`) in the column list of its query, but then it never calls `openFile`. How is it expecting to get the data from my `ContentProvider`? Is it improperly just trying to directly open the file returned in the _data column instead of accessing the `ContentProvider`? Is there anything I can do to provide Facebook an image without writing it to external storage?

Comment: Does the Facebook app crash? If so, what is the stack trace?

Comment: @CommonsWare No, it just displays a Facebook input entry form with a gray box for where the picture would go, but it has no picture in it (when I use the code in the linked question), or it displays the input entry form with no box at all (if I return null from the query function, or null in the "_data" column of the return value).

Answer (score 0):

My "solution" was to make files readable `file.setReadable(true, false);` No need for android external storage permissions.

FB never asks for a file with `openFile(Uri uri, String mode)` and acceses files directly.

Probably there is some flag or xml param in provider, but i tested everything i could find and had no luck with FB. Every other share app worked fine.

Here is [**GitHub Demo**](https://github.com/varren/Screenshoter/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/varren/screenshoter)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this addresses your specific problem, but I've encountered a similar problem:

1. I provide a Uri to an image inside the private directory of my app.
2. Through a ContentProvider, I provide access to it by returning the following in `openFile()`:

   ```
   return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
   ```
3. When sharing to Facebook, the image doesn't appear. Every other app, however, does work. Debugging calls into my ContentProvider, I see that Facebook does indeed query the ContentProvider, and `openFile()` is hit. Nevertheless, the image doesn't appear.

After much head scratching, I realized I was returning `null` as the MIME type. I changed the result of `getType()` to return "image/png", and that was it: Facebook accepted my image.

[See also my question and answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547465/sharing-image-from-app-private-storage-to-facebook/38547466#38547466)